# existing PHP Laravel 4 integration with wardrobe CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, laravel, laravel-4, blogs

I have developed an web application in PHP Laravel 4 Framework and I wish to have a blog section which manage by using the wardrobe CMS. Is that possible to integrate the wardrobe CMS into the existing web application for the blog section only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!

You just have to add "core" to your composer application packages: https://packagist.org/packages/wardrobe/core

Check the "Installing Wardrobe In An Existing Laravel Application" section: https://github.com/wardrobecms/core

Comment: Thanks so much bro =D Actually I saw it as well. 
Just need some confirmation